# How to handle mouseover on element in UI in selenium webdriver using javascript

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, safaridriver, browserstack, safari

I don't want to use action class as its failing for some browser. therefore I am using JS but I ended up with " arguments[0].hover is not a function" error for using arguments[0].hover();

```
WebElement ele = browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[contains(text(),'Basic example')]"))
    Actions builder = new Actions(browser.driver)
 ((JavascriptExecutor) browser.driver).executeScript("arguments[0].hover();", ele);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser.driver, 60);
    WebElement selenium =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(ele));
    ((JavascriptExecutor) browser.driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", ele);
    waitFor(WAIT_TIME){$(By.xpath(".//a[contains(text(),'Basic example')]")).css("text-decoration-line") == "underline"}
    assert $(By.xpath(".//a[contains(text(),'Basic example')]")).css("text-decoration-line") == "underline": "No underline is displaying after hover mouse"
```

Url tested on:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

Answer (score 1):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp

click() is an action but hover() is a event , so calling hover over the element doesn't do anything . It is used define what should happen when user hovers over the element.

Using action class is the best way , but still if you want to use javascript use:

```
arguments[0].focus()
```

**Note:** in the example the link is inside iframe you should switch to that first

Comment: Using arguments[0].focus() it will only focus on the path given but basically, I want to move the mouse on the element given as I need to validate the colour interaction post mouse on so arguments[0].focus() didn't help much.

Comment: why you don't want to use actions ?

Comment: action class is passing with chrome, firefox browsers but not with Safari & IE, its throwing MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException error .

Comment: So it's passing for all safari browser capability except Catalina safari 13.1 throwing an error MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException

Comment: please add your code how are you moving to that element

Comment: Actions action = new Actions (browser.driver);

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser.driver, 50);
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//a[contains(text(),'Basic example')]")));
 action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();

Answer (score 1):

In every testing company, automation testing services teams may face this type issue related to focusing a webElement. This can be done by doing mousehover actions by selenium or by java script.

Below is one way of getting the focus on webElement:

C#:
((IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", webElement);

Java:
((JavaScriptExecutor)webDriver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", webElement);

Here webElement is the element on which we are bringing the focus and can be passed as a variable like above.